# Why zone-plate photography is not monochromatic?

Tags: optics

[Zone-plate photography](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/11552/what-is-a-zone-plate) produces somewhat ["blurry" photos](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Christmas_with_zone_plate.jpg). However, according to Fresnel's equation, I'd expect the resulting photos to be somewhat monochromatic, due to the [dependence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zone_plate#Design_and_manufacture) between $r,f$ and $\lambda$:

$$f = \frac{2 r_{N} \Delta r_{N}}{\lambda}$$

i.e. if the rings are "properly" constructed, we'll have a different focal point for different wavelengths, which contradicts the fact that in [the photo mentioned above](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Christmas_with_zone_plate.jpg) we can distinctly see red, green and blue.

Comment: I'd suggest putting in representative numbers for $r_N$, $\Delta r_N$, and calculate $f$ for three wavelengths, red (say, 650 nm),  green (530 nm) and blue (450 nm).  You might be able to figure out *part* of the answer yourself if you do that.  You also need to consider depth of focus, which is a little more complicated... the focal spot remains small for a certain range of image distances.

Answer (score 1):

(Following @garyp's comment)

We'll indeed have different focal points for different wavelengths:

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial \lambda}=-\frac{2 r_{N} \Delta r_{N}}{\lambda^2}$$

taking typical values of $r_N \sim 10^{-2}\mathrm{m}$, $\Delta r_N \sim 10^{-3}\mathrm{m}$, $\lambda\sim 5\cdot 10^{-7}\mathrm{m}$, we get:

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial \lambda} \sim -\frac{2\cdot 10^{-2}\cdot 10^{-3}}{(5\cdot 10^{-7})^2} \sim -\frac{10^{-5}}{10^{-15}} = -10^{10}$$

so $\Delta f \approx \frac{\partial f}{\partial \lambda}\cdot \Delta\lambda$ (where $\Delta\lambda$ is in the order of 100nm) is in the order of $10^{-3}$, i.e. a few millimeters over the whole optical range, which is too small of a difference to cause any monochromatic effect.

> You also need to consider depth of focus, which is a little more complicated... the focal spot remains small for a certain range of image distances. – @garyp